# Convertir arrays asociativos a un arreglo matricial

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo los siguientes arrays:

```
$empresa_A = [
    ['cuenta' => 101, 'nombre_cuenta' => 'cuenta A', 'id_proveedor' => 1, 'nombre_proveedor' => 'provedor A', 'monto_empresa_A' => 5.00],
    ['cuenta' => 102, 'nombre_cuenta' => 'cuenta B', 'id_proveedor' => 2, 'nombre_proveedor' => 'provedor B', 'monto_empresa_A' => 2.00],
    ['cuenta' => 103, 'nombre_cuenta' => 'cuenta C', 'id_proveedor' => 3, 'nombre_proveedor' => 'provedor C', 'monto_empresa_A' => 1.00]
];

$empresa_B = [
    ['cuenta' => 103, 'nombre_cuenta' => 'cuenta C', 'id_proveedor' => 3, 'nombre_proveedor' => 'provedor C', 'monto_empresa_B' => 8.00],
    ['cuenta' => 104, 'nombre_cuenta' => 'cuenta D', 'id_proveedor' => 4, 'nombre_proveedor' => 'provedor D', 'monto_empresa_B' => 6.00],
];

$empresa_C = [
    ['cuenta' => 104, 'nombre_cuenta' => 'cuenta D', 'id_proveedor' => 4, 'nombre_proveedor' => 'provedor D', 'monto_empresa_C' => 2.00],
];
```

Intento hacer un solo array cuando estos coinciden en el campo "cuenta" y en el campo "id_proveedor":

```
$grupo = [
    ['cuenta' => 101, 'nombre_cuenta' => 'cuenta A', 'id_proveedor' => 1, 'nombre_proveedor' => 'provedor A', 'monto_empresa_A' => 5.00, 'monto_empresa_B' => 0.00, 'monto_empresa_C' => 0.00],
    ['cuenta' => 102, 'nombre_cuenta' => 'cuenta B', 'id_proveedor' => 2, 'nombre_proveedor' => 'provedor B', 'monto_empresa_A' => 2.00, 'monto_empresa_B' => 0.00, 'monto_empresa_C' => 0.00],
    ['cuenta' => 103, 'nombre_cuenta' => 'cuenta C', 'id_proveedor' => 3, 'nombre_proveedor' => 'provedor C', 'monto_empresa_A' => 1.00, 'monto_empresa_B' => 8.00, 'monto_empresa_C' => 0.00],
    ['cuenta' => 104, 'nombre_cuenta' => 'cuenta D', 'id_proveedor' => 4, 'nombre_proveedor' => 'provedor D', 'monto_empresa_A' => 0.00, 'monto_empresa_B' => 6.00, 'monto_empresa_C' => 2.00] 
];
```

Intente lo siguiente, pero no me funciona:

```
$grupo = [];

foreach ($empresa_A as $key1 => $value1) {
    foreach ($empresa_B as $key2 => $value2) {
        if ($value1['cuenta'] = $value2['cuenta'] || $value1['id_proveedor'] = $value2['id_proveedor']) {
            $grupo[$value1]["monto_empresa_B"] = $value2;
            break;
        } else {
            $grupo[$value1]["monto_empresa_B"] = 0;
        }
    }

    foreach ($empresa_C as $key3 => $value3) {
        if ($value1['cuenta'] = $value3['cuenta'] || $value1['id_proveedor'] = $value3['id_proveedor']) {
            $grupo[$value1]["monto_empresa_C"] = $value3;
            break;
        } else {
            $grupo[$value1]["monto_empresa_C"] = 0;
        }
    }
    
}
```

A continuacion dejo una imagen del reporte que estoy buscando:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que con lo anterior me logro explicar, pero escribo el presente parrafo, ya que el stackoverflow me dice que es mas codigo y que agregue mas detalles. UU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dado que ya tienes unos arrays, podrias hacer un merge_recursive de cada uno, dentro de una lista:

```
$lista = array_merge_recursive($empresa_A, $empresa_B, $empresa_C);
```

esto te da un resultado como:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cuenta] => 101
            [nombre_cuenta] => cuenta A
            [id_proveedor] => 1
            [nombre_proveedor] => provedor A
            [monto_empresa_A] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cuenta] => 102
            [nombre_cuenta] => cuenta B
            [id_proveedor] => 2
            [nombre_proveedor] => provedor B
            [monto_empresa_A] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [cuenta] => 103
            [nombre_cuenta] => cuenta C
            [id_proveedor] => 3
            [nombre_proveedor] => provedor C
            [monto_empresa_A] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [cuenta] => 103
            [nombre_cuenta] => cuenta C
            [id_proveedor] => 3
            [nombre_proveedor] => provedor C
            [monto_empresa_B] => 8
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [cuenta] => 104
            [nombre_cuenta] => cuenta D
            [id_proveedor] => 4
            [nombre_proveedor] => provedor D
            [monto_empresa_B] => 6
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [cuenta] => 104
            [nombre_cuenta] => cuenta D
            [id_proveedor] => 4
            [nombre_proveedor] => provedor D
            [monto_empresa_C] => 2
        )
)
```

Como ves, ya tienes todo en un mismo array. El problema es que tienes luego algunos campos que deberian estar agrupados (pero estan separados).
aqui entonces si usaria un foreach, iterando entre cada elemento, y guardando los datos en otra lista. En esta ultima, vamos a utilizar un campo clave (he elegido el `id_proveedor`, creo que es unico en tu ejemplo)

```
$lista2 = [];
foreach($lista as $item) {
    $lista2[$item['id_proveedor']] =empty($lista2[$item['id_proveedor']]) ? $item: array_merge($lista2[$item['id_proveedor']], $item);
}
```

en el bucle, miro si esta vacio el array anterior con la clave id_proveedor. Si esta vacio, le asigno el Item (del bucle). Si ya existe esa clave, hago un merge de lo que hay con el item actual del bucle.

Esto te resulta en un array como:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [cuenta] => 101
            [nombre_cuenta] => cuenta A
            [id_proveedor] => 1
            [nombre_proveedor] => provedor A
            [monto_empresa_A] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [cuenta] => 102
            [nombre_cuenta] => cuenta B
            [id_proveedor] => 2
            [nombre_proveedor] => provedor B
            [monto_empresa_A] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [cuenta] => 103
            [nombre_cuenta] => cuenta C
            [id_proveedor] => 3
            [nombre_proveedor] => provedor C
            [monto_empresa_A] => 1
            [monto_empresa_B] => 8
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [cuenta] => 104
            [nombre_cuenta] => cuenta D
            [id_proveedor] => 4
            [nombre_proveedor] => provedor D
            [monto_empresa_B] => 6
            [monto_empresa_C] => 2
        )
)
```

aqui ya puedes ver que el resultado tiene, en el caso del ultimo item, los valores del monto_empresa_B y monto_empresa_c en el mismo item.

**NOTA:** Esto podria resolver tu problema en especifico. Es posible que tengas que adaptar algo. Un problema que te puede dar es que, si cambian algunos campos, el merge sobreescribe y "prioriza" lo que tenga el item sobre lo que tenga el array almacenamiento. Revisa si te sirve asi.